# US label value map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, choroplethr

I am using a data result
([https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0zK9xcdOi1sQ1JaZFZYX1FQaUU/view?usp=sharing])

What I am trying to do is color the states of the US map based on the label value in that state, using the maps package.

I am trying use following code, but it doesn't work.

```
library(choroplethr)

gtd <- read.csv("/Users/urAD_Jeff/Documents/Image analysis/result PNG/state.CSV")

statelabel<- ddply(gtd, .(y), "nrow")

colnames(statelabel) <- c("label", "value")

statelabel$label <- tolower(statelabel$label)
statelabel$label <- gsub(" (u.s. state)", "", statelabel$label, fixed=TRUE)

choroplethr(statlabel, lod="state")
```

The wanted result image looks like :
[image]

Comment: What doesn't work? Also, you are using "City.CSV" and the file on Google Drive is "State.CSV". There is also a typo `tolower(statelabels$label)`. And `choroplethr` is deprecated as of choroplethr version 2.0.0.

Comment: I solved the first and second problem. what the 3rd means? what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the closest (you have missing states):

```
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)
library(plyr)

gtd <- read.csv("State.CSV")

statelabel <- gtd[,2:3]
colnames(statelabel) <- c("region", "value")

statelabel$region <- tolower(statelabel$region)
statelabel$region <- gsub(" (u.s. state)", "", statelabel$region, fixed=TRUE)

state_choropleth(statelabel)
# Warning in super$initialize(map.df, user.df) :
#   Your data.frame contains the following regions which are not mappable:
#   washington (state), unknown
# Warning in self$bind() :
#   The following regions were missing and are being set to NA: north dakota, 
#   rhode island, south dakota, district of columbia
```

[image]

Comment: Using library(plyr) will occur error, I change to  library(dplyr). Thanks!